# IP Address Valid format (RegEx) Change

Tags: regex

I am using the following Regular Expression to validate IP Address, that works fine for general, but my requirement is first part/last of the IP Address should not accept '0'. The format should be `[1-255].[0-255].[0-255].[1-255]`, Can you please help, how to change below RegEX?

```
^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.
([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$
```

Thanks,

Comment: Split on dot and test each value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
[01]?\\d\\d?
```

is used to match *one digit* numbers, *two digit* numbers and *three digit* numbers *starting with **zero** or **one***. Just split that for the last part of the IP into:

```
[01]?\\d\\d|[1-9]
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/zU7gM8/1)

Comment: OP has additional constrains besides just matching digits starting with 0 or 1.  For example he also said that the value matched can't be greater than 255, and must be at least 1 in some cases.

Comment: @markspace, if you read the his question and his current regex, he has already fulfilled the other constraints and just wants the last part to be > 0 (as opposed to >= 0).

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
^([1]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.
([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([1]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you too.

```
^((2[1-5][1-5]|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9]))\.((2[1-5][1-5]|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d))\.((2[1-5][1-5]|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d))\.((2[1-5][1-5]|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9]))$
```

Breakdown:

```
Group A: 1 - 255
case 1: 1-9
case 2: 10-99
case 3: 100-199
case 4: 200 - 255

Group B: 0-255
case 1: 0-9
case 2: 10-99
case 3: 100-199
case 4: 200 - 255

Group C: 0-255
case 1: 0-9
case 2: 10-99
case 3: 100-199
case 4: 200 - 255

Group D: 1-255
case 1: 1-9
case 2: 10-99
case 3: 100-199
case 4: 200 - 255
```